# Apache as reverse proxy more resources

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

I'm moving a big directory of images from an HTTP server to another and I cannot change any configuration.

I would like my user don't even suppose that a moving in progress. So I thought to add an Apache httpd server configured as reverse proxy in front of both the servers.

This reverse proxy when a resource is not found in the destination should try to get it in the origin server.

Is there any way to do this using mod_rewrite or some standard Apache httpd module?

The resources are not on the front-end server, but on two back-end servers.

Comment: Edited to clearly state that the resources are not on the local storage of the apache server. Can you add details of your existing proxy config?

Comment: Thanks for your support, I was just thinking same thing. But I cannot see your edit, may be it was overwritten by mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a reverse proxy with Apache httpd 2.2, but it is not possible do it using only apache directives. So I had to use a simple PHP script in order to check remote url existence.

When a new request comes, it check the existence of current path on Server A and, if successfully found, it reverse proxy the request on same server. 
On the other hand, if the requested path is not found on Server A, it implements a rewrite rule reverse proxy on serverB.

I have used a `RewriteMap` with `MapType` `prg:` and a PHP script.
There are the Apache directives:

```
# Please pay attention to RewriteLock
# this directive must be defined in server config context
RewriteLock /tmp/if_url_exists.lock

RewriteEngine On

ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyRequests Off

RewriteMap  url_exists "prg:/usr/bin/php /opt/local/scripts/url_exists.php"
RewriteCond ${url_exists:http://serverA%{REQUEST_URI}}   >0
RewriteRule .            http://serverA%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]

RewriteRule .            http://serverB%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]
```

Here comes the interesting and tricky part. 
This is the `url_exists.php` script, executed by Apache. It is waiting on the standard input stream and write into standard output.
This scripts return `1` if the resource is found and readable, otherwise `0`.
Actually it is quite simple because it implements only an HTTP request using the HEAD method.

```
<?php

function check_if_url_exists($line) {
    $curl_inst = curl_init($line);

    curl_setopt( $curl_inst, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt( $curl_inst, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 1);
    curl_setopt( $curl_inst, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 180);
    curl_setopt( $curl_inst, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt( $curl_inst, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

    // Exclude the body from the output and request method is set to HEAD.
    curl_setopt( $curl_inst, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt( $curl_inst, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt( $curl_inst, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $raw = curl_exec($curl_inst);

    curl_close($curl_inst);

    return ($raw != false) ? true : false;

}

set_time_limit(0);
$keyboard = fopen("php://stdin","r");

while (true) {
    $line = trim(fgets($keyboard));
    if (!empty($line)) {
        $str = (check_if_url_exists($line)) ? "1" : "0";
        error_log($line. " ".$str);
        echo $str."\n";
    } else {
        error_log('empty line!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for remote resources in RewriteCond you can use the following:

> '-U' (is existing URL, via subrequest) Checks whether or not
>   TestString is a valid URL, accessible via all the server's
>   currently-configured access controls for that path. This uses an
>   internal subrequest to do the check, so use it with care - it can
>   impact your server's performance!

I never personally used it. But it works like testing for a file existence and the like.

You can then have a RewriteRule that proxies the request (the [P] option).

Comment: Thanks, it seems just what I was looking for. I'll try it immediately.

Comment: Did it work? I'm curious as I never used that option!

Comment: Yesterday my idea was rejected. I suppose the main worry was the warning about the use of subrequest and related impact on performance (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond ). Anyway, if I have time today, I'll try your suggestion at least as proof of concept.

Comment: Hi, yesterday (at last) I have tested the `-U` option. As far as I understood, it is impossibile to check if an external url is valid, this option apply only to internal url.